# Get REQUEST body from RetrofitError

Tags: android, retrofit

Is there a way to get the request (not response) body from a RetrofitError? I'm logging client-side errors to my server and it would be awesome if I could include the json I used to make the failed request in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bunch of questions about that on stack. 
No, there is no such option out of the box in 1.6 (except for analysing URL that caused exception). I have read ?2 weeks ago that work on retrofit 2.0 should be starting in one week so maybe in near future?